# Manually running container exists with code 145

Tags: powershell, docker, asp.net-core

I am trying to manually run the image, that is created through Visual Studio 2017, using docker commands in powershell, with the following command

> docker run -d -p 12345:80 webapplication1:dev

But the container exits immediately with Code 145.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker images
REPOSITORY         TAG        IMAGE ID            CREATED           SIZE
webapplication1    dev        b4f4585be3d1        6 minutes ago     305MB

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                COMMAND                 CREATED        STATUS                        PORTS                   NAMES
41aa3e20e4be  webapplication1:dev  "dotnet WebApplica..."  11 minutes ago Exited (145) 11 minutes ago                           condescending_shaw
```

Running docker logs condescending_shaw shows the following

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker logs condescending_shaw
  Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
```

Currently I have  no clue what the Code 145 means and why I cannot run the image manually. So any help what I am doing wrong would be fine. Running the app via Visual Studio 2017 and Docker SupportTools is no problem. The application works just fine.

I also tried creating new images with the Dockerfile. But those containers also exit with 145.

Heres the Dockerfile for reference

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application probably requieres the SDK and not just the .NET core runtime you are using. Try to use this image instead 
https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore-build/.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to manually run an image from VS2017 is to switch from Debug to Release, then running from VS will build an image that you can manually run. This is because, by default, the docker-compose.ci.build.yml will include the aspnetcore-build image, which is the dotnet SDK that exit code 145 is complaining about. The Debug version will not include this by default. The Release version does.